# Errors while trying to package R scripts

Tags: r

I was trying to package a couple of R scripts I had written for a project using the instructions here:

http://hilaryparker.com/2014/04/29/writing-an-r-package-from-scratch/

Everything goes fine but when I try `install("STG")` (STG is the name I chose) then I get errors of the sort:

> cannot open file 'STG_sub_function.R': No such file or directory

By some strategic debug statements it seems the errors are due to a path issue. Basically I've kept the main function & other R files all inside the R folder created by devtools within STG.

But a getwd() tells me that the installer is trying to find them all one dir level above.

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: If you're using devtools, you're better off following instructions from the source. http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz

Comment: Just a random guess based on the error: there should be no sourcing of scripts in an R package. Anything you want goes in a function.

Comment: @joran: Perfect guess. I am indeed sourcing. I'll try and get rid of that. So if a function is in another R script in the same dir does it become visible automatically?

Comment: Basically, yes. Once you switch to packages, stop thinking of any of your files as "scripts". Your .r files at that point contain functions, and all of your functions can see all your other functions. If you want some to be visible to users, you need to explicitly export them. And if you want functions from other packages, you need to import them.